# use Jelly Bean's Simple Secure Pairing ( Bluetooth ) to pair with NFC

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

As of #io2012 and [JellyBean doc](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/) there is now a way to pair bluetooth devices via NFC.

That sounds really nice, but I cannot find any documentation about it.

I am especially interested to know if that works with SPP modules that do not support SDP - can I simply write some NFC tag with the PIN-Info and the device gets paired? Would help a lot as a lot of users, that have problems with the PIN-pairing process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two kinds of Bluetooth pairing NDEF messages that are supported by JellyBean. The standardized one defined by the [Bluetooth SIG together with the NFC Forum](http://members.nfc-forum.org/resources/AppDocs/NFCForum_AD_BTSSP_1_0.pdf) and the (older) proprietary one defined by Nokia (see "What is the tag format to connect the Nokia 6131 NFC with a Bluetooth imaging device?" at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_6131_NFC_-_FAQs#SDK_APIs for some details).

The standardized one does not provide support for PIN. It only supports the new Simple Pairing method. The Nokia-type message has support for PIN. However, when reading the relevant source code from Android that parses such Bluetooth paring NDEF messages (`parseNokia()` in [HandoverManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/nfc/handover/HandoverManager.java)) you can see that the PIN is not even read out from the NDEF message. So in the end only the built-in PINs in the Android Bluetooth manager will be tried (default ones like 0000 and 1234) to set up a connection if the device is not already known and paired earlier before reading the tag (in which case the NFC tag merely functions as a way to activate the connection).

I also have the impression that this new functionality in Android is firstly supposed to work with audio devices such as head sets. I cannot tell whether it also works with SSP devices (no device to test with myself).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Do you know any app that could write tags like this?

Comment: [NFC TagWriter by NXP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter) as mentioned in the other answer (enable the Professional Edition as UI mode in the settings to make it visible). You may want to experiment with the byte-order of the MAC address; there seems to be some confusion about what the proper order is.

Comment: thanks & enjoy the bounty - I was overlooking that feature inside NFC TagWriter by NXP as I didn't know you have to switch to Professional Edition first

Comment: "Bluetooth SIG together with the NFC Forum" link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can quite simply create an NFC tag with Bluetooth pairing information. Anyhow it will only work for now when the device uses a default pin as Android will only try the default pin 0000 to what I know. you can program such a tag using the NFC TagWriter by NXP.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at Stanford's [EasyNFC library on GitHub](https://github.com/Mobisocial/EasyNFC).

Especially the [BluetoothConnector](http://mobisocial.github.com/EasyNFC/apidocs/reference/mobisocial/nfc/addon/BluetoothConnector.html) seems interesting as it "Helps developers set up long-lasting Bluetooth connections across devices".

Comment: Hm looks like this solution only handles phone<>phone - my use-case is Phone<->SPP Module - thanks anyway - will dig through the code - perhaps I find a way how to adopt this to my use-case - if I find a clue in there and there is no better answer till then you get the bounty ;-)