# Avoid losing focus in Android when Bluetooth PIN is asked

Tags: android, bluetooth

When my App connects for the first time with a particular device via Bluetooth, a dialog appears asking to type in the PIN. The problem is that if the user touches the screen outside the dialog, it loses focus and dissapears... an from then on, it's just trouble, the user must force the App to close, or go back to a previous state and restart the pairing process...

So, my questions are: Is there any way to avoid (programmatically) losing focus on that system-generated-dialog? Is that the normal behaviour of the system or should I check my code for bugs/conceptual errors?

Comment: It's a system dialog... I didn't implement it, but just happens to appear automaticaly... I guess it's part of the Android Bluetooth API but didn't find much information in the website

Comment: This only happens in Android 4.0+ right?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4.0+ [setCanceledOnTouchOutside (boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29) is set to true by default for dialogs, which is why clicks outside the dialog cancel it.

There isn't any way to override the `ontouch` event for a system dialog though.

Comment: Yeah, in fact the problem is that I don't know how to adress the system dialogs! In the other hand, probably I'm not supposed to adress them, since it would be some sort of security issue... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

for 4.1 devices perhaps simple secure pairing is an possible workaround - but it is not yet well documented - facing similar problems with the pairing - and hope for that to change the issue a bit [use Jelly Bean's Simple Secure Pairing ( Bluetooth ) to pair with NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500140/use-jelly-beans-simple-secure-pairing-bluetooth)